# Why the query manipulation is not working?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I made a handler factory function to handle some API. There I have a populate method to populate a field in database.
After execution I saw my populate method is not working when I use query manipulation like . . .

```
        let query = await Model.findById(req.params.id)
        
        if(popOptions) query = query.populate(popOptions)
            
        

         const doc = await query
```

after going to the api by this controller I get the query without population

But when I use this code below using if else statement it gives me the expected output that is the query I made with population of required fields

```
     let query
        if(popOptions) {
            query = await Model.findById(req.params.id).populate(popOptions)
        }
        else {
            query = await Model.findById(req.params.id)
        }
```

I just want to know why this happens. I'm fairly new to mongoDB and express

Comment: Try putting `query = await query.populate(popOption)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between

```
await Model.findById(req.params.id).populate(popOptions)
```

and

```
await (await Model.findById(req.params.id)).populate(popOptions)
```

Try this:

```
let query = Model.findById(req.params.id)
        
if(popOptions) query = query.populate(popOptions)

const doc = await query
```